# Custom Stepper in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tuAMy.png)

I want to achieve this kind of stepper

So far i have tried using [AnotherStepper](https://pub.dev/packages/another_stepper) package from `pub.dev`

```
 List<StepperData> stepperData = [
    StepperData(
      title: StepperText(
        "Order Placed",
        textStyle: const TextStyle(
          color: Colors.grey,
        ),
      ),
      subtitle: StepperText("Your order has been placed"),
    ),
    StepperData(
      title: StepperText("Preparing"),
      subtitle: StepperText("Your order is being prepared"),
    ),
    StepperData(
      title: StepperText("On the way"),
      subtitle: StepperText(
          "Our delivery executive is on the way to deliver your item"),
    ),
    StepperData(
      title: StepperText("Delivered",
          textStyle: const TextStyle(
            color: Colors.grey,
          )),
    ),
  ];
```

```
 AnotherStepper(
                // this is removed 
                
                // dotWidget: Container(
                //   padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                //   decoration: BoxDecoration(
                //       color: Colors.red,
                //       borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(30))),
                //   child: Icon(Icons.fastfood, color: Colors.white),
                // ),                      
                stepperList: stepperData,
                stepperDirection: Axis.vertical,
                gap: 20,
                iconWidth: 24,
                iconHeight: 24,
                activeBarColor: Colors.green,
                inActiveBarColor: Colors.grey,
                activeIndex: 1,
                barThickness: 8,
              ),
```

I want to conditionally grey out the style of the `subtitle` based on the `activeIndex`  and i want to achieve the dot color. How can i do that ? An assist would be greatly appreciated.

Desired Image

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tuAMy.png)

OutputImage

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lGGow.png)

Answer (score 2):

You need a simple if else statement to achieve that
define isActive with a state manegment

```
   StepperData(
      title: StepperText(
        "Order Placed",
        textStyle: const TextStyle(
          color: isActive ?Colors.grey:Colors.black,
        ),
      ),
      subtitle: StepperText("Your order has been placed",
         textStyle: const TextStyle(
          color: isActive ?Colors.grey:Colors.black,
        ),),
    ),
```

Comment: Can you ellaborate further , and give a live example and this solves only 30% of the problem